# Using MessagingCenter for communicating between ViewModels to Views and Navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

In a XAML Page (A View), I have a bunch of controls like Pickers that are binded to a ViewModel, called "NegotiationVM"

For example, I have a Picker binded to one of those properties "NegotiatorSelected" which returns an object "Negotiator". 
My corcern is about a pair of buttons beside of that negotiator picker, are not binded to that Negotiation ViewModel or any Command, those buttons are for Adding or Editing a Negotiator. Since I'm trying to follow MVVM pattern (with no framework yet...) I would like to know what is the best practice here.

My approach is in the First ViewModel create Commands that calls methods that send an instance of the child ViewModel to the View, so when this receive it, then navigates to the child View.

```
public class NegotiationVM: INotifyPropertyChanged{

  public NegotiationVM{
    AddNegotiatorCommand = new Command(AddNegotiator,()=> !IsBusy);
  }
...
  public void AddNegotiator(){
    negotiatorvm = new NegotiatiorVM(_client)
    MessagingCenter.Send<NegotiationVM,NegotiatorVM>(this,"NegotiatiorVM",negotiatiorvm)
  }
  public void EditNegotiator(){
    negotiatorvm = new NegotiatiorVM(_client,_negotiatior)
    MessagingCenter.Send<NegotiationVM,NegotiatorVM>(this,"NegotiatiorVM",negotiatiorvm)
  }
}
```

So in NegotiationView I do this:

```
<!-- More controls binded to NegotiationVM -->
...
<!--  -->
<Picker x:Name="pickerNegotiator" Title="Select..." ItemsSource="{Binding Negotiatorsofthisnegotiation}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNegotiator}" />
 <Button x:Name="btnAddNegotiator" Text="➕" BackgroundColor="#3276b1"  TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="35" Command="{Binding AddNegotiatorCommand}" />
<Button x:Name="btnEditNegotiator" Text="" BackgroundColor="#3276b1"  TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="35"  Command="{Binding EditNegotiatorCommand}" />
<!-- ... -->
```

and in code-behind:

```
...
public NegotiationView(){
   negotiationvm = new NegotiationVM();
   this.BindingContext = negotiationvm;
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NegotiationVM,NegociatorVM>(this,"NegotiatorVM",AddEditNegotiator);
}
...
void AddEditNegotiator(NegotiationVM arg1, NegotiatorVM vm)
        {
            NegotiatorPage negotiatorPage = new NegotiatorPage()
            {
                BindingContext = vm
            };
            Navigation.PushAsync(negotiatorPage);
        }
```

So using MessagingCenter to communicate a ViewModel to a View in order to bind it to a child view and then Navigate to its view, is this a good practice considering that I'm not using any MVVM framework? Is this approach is making ViewModel from View decoupled enough? I read some comments that using MessagingCenter is not a good idea.

Comment: I think you're using messages because you need to perform navigation from views.

Comment: Navigation needs to be initiated from Viewmodel

Comment: @oarrivi Not only that, I also need additional information containted in the ViewModel, as an edit or a new Negotiator.

Comment: @oarrivi My code was with Navigation initiated in the Viewmodel, but changed it to this current example because I wasn't sure about it was a good practice. So, it is then?

Comment: I meant, navigation must be carried out by View Models. If you're wondering how a view model can access Navigation class, the answer is, they can't. 
View Models manage navigation through a INavigationService which will be implemented by a view in charge of navigation.
There are many NavigationService implementations in blogs and frameworks. All of them very similar.
For example an implementation used in MVVM Light. Actually it is not part of this library, but the interface and its implementation is simple:
http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/nav1.cshtml

Comment: @Mr_LinDowsMac, there is no problem using messages. But I believe message make code more complicated to read and maintain since is not easy to find out who and where is subscribing a message.

Comment: @oarrivi Fair. The only reason why I used Messages is because I can't implement a MVVM library at this point. 

So, considering that I'm not using a INavigationService, is it better (or less messy) to use `Navigation.Pushasync()` from viewmodel, or from the callback method after received message in the view?

Comment: INavigationService is not part of any library nor framework. You can implement it as suggested in link above.